# How to stop Avaudiosession from deactivating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, quickblox, avaudiosession

I want to play a song through speaker while being able to receive a video call using Quickblox.

My audio rates are getting messed up.
And also a bigger a problem is when the call ends quickblox framework sets audio session to deactivated state. i.e
  [Avaudiosession sharedInstance]setActive:NO....

How do I stop this from happening?

Or is there a way the above mentioned scenario can be handled.??

I have read through google for a month now and still didn't find any suitable answers or any guidelines.
Can anyone help me with this problem/??

Answer (score 2):

First, to allow `AVAudioSession` to work with other `AVAudioSessions`, you'll need to set up the option `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers` when initializing it:

```
NSError *sessionError = NULL;
    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                                    withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                                          error:&sessionError];

    if(!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error setting category Audio Session: %@", [sessionError localizedDescription]);
    }
```

To handle interruptions (a call, alarm, etc..), you should set up an observer for interruptions to the `NSNotificationCenter` where you'll be able to handle the activation/deactivation of the `AVAudioSession` if necessary:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption:)
                                                     name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                                   object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];
```

The NSNotification will carry the Type of Interruption and Key:

```
- (void)handleAudioSessionInterruption:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSNumber *interruptionType = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey];
    NSNumber *interruptionOption = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey];

    switch (interruptionType.unsignedIntegerValue) {
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan:{
            // • Audio has stopped, already inactive
            // • Change state of UI, etc., to reflect non-playing state
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan");

        } break;
        case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded:{
            // • Make session active
            // • Update user interface
            // • AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume option
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded");
            if (interruptionOption.unsignedIntegerValue == AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume) {
                // Here you should continue playback.
            }
        } break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! But unfortunately did not solve the issue. I checked the logs I am getting this error :  AVAudioSession.mm:692: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

also :  AVAudioSession.mm:692: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

Comment: @saurabh2810 The above example is for handling interrupts from other applications. You are receiving the running I/O error because some other part of the SAME application is using the AV. Check your classes or if hybrid your plugins might be having contention.